# Quit company and work for another company that has the same end client

Tags: job-search, ethics

So here is something I want to know before I make a move. I am employed by Company A to work for their client. Now I'm looking for a new job and is contacted by Company B, but they both work for the same client. Is it ok or ethical to accept it?

Job position from Company A is different from position in Company B.

Comment: Ensure you get a substantial raise.

Comment: @Fattie, I will make sure but would it be ethical to do it? 
I kind of see it not ethical if the positions were both the same and I moved because of a higher pay. But the positions are different. Or is it just depends on what a person feels/think?

Comment: The only thing I could offer on this is, it is fairly common for a developer X to move from one agency A to another B.  My feeling is it is probably "OK".

Comment: If there's a NDA in your previous employment contract, make sure you don't violate it. If there's a NCC, you probably need to consult a lawyer.

Answer (score 1):

**It happens all the time. There is no problem at all.**

Often people will joke, that although the former colleague switched jobs s/he ended up doing the same work for the same client.

Just make sure you're not burning bridges in another way with your previous employer and with the client. For example if you leave the current project in a critical phase, the client might not be as happy to work with you in your next position.

Answer (score 0):

It is not like you are stealing their client, they already have a deal with Company B. Since you are not taking A's revenue pipeline to B or leaking trade secrets that might allow B to acquire A's market share, there are no ethical issues with this.

Think about industry giants (FAANG, major airlines etc.) that work with sometimes hundreds of vendors. There are people that move between those vendors all the time.